# Uploading files using AJAX and JQuery in an ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, file-upload

I have several input type files in my asp.net Web Form.

How can I upload files to Server using Jquery, AJAX and C#?

The uploaders are generated programmatically so I cannot upload the files using code behind.

Also, many files must be uploaded at once.

Is there anyway I read the file via Jquery, send it via AJAX to server and upload it there?

THanks

Comment: There are A LOT of articles and plugins on this topic if you simple Google.



https://www.google.com/search?q=.net+ajax+file+upload&aq=f&oq=.net+ajax+file+upload&aqs=chrome.0.57j60j62l2.4011&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=ajax+file+upload+site:stackoverflow.com&oq=ajax+file+upload+site:stackoverflow.com&gs_l=serp.3...5790.12955.0.13130.32.30.2.0.0.3.463.6693.0j10j15j3j1.29.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.XujmIzUsh4k&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43148975,d.b2I&fp=95c9c19312d4e19&biw=1014&bih=759

Comment: @Shenaniganz I googled a lot, but most of them are used in a php context, others use html5 which is supported by all browsers. Could you post the link of just ONE of all those articles for asp.net ajax jquery fileupload?

Comment: I do this with jQuery and VB.NET all the time.  I use uploadify and it works great! [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)

Comment: use "-php" in Google search query.
Quick question. Is it MVC or just asp.net app ?

Comment: @zgood uploadify uses flash, right?

Comment: @Shenaniganz no mvc, just web forms

Comment: Yes it does use flash, but there is also an HTML5 version. Can you not use flash?

Comment: @zgood i need a cross-browser solution, i cannot limit users

Comment: flash is cross-browser friendly, you just can't use flash on a tablet, but you cannot upload files from a tablet anyways so it's a moot point.

Comment: @zgood you certainly can upload files from a tablet.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com).  It does not use flash or java.  In fact, it does not have any required dependencies.  An optional jQuery plug-in is provided, if you use jQuery though.

Support: IE10-7, Chrome, Firefox, Safari (OS X), as well as Android tablets and phones, along with IOS6 tablets and phones (iPhone & iPad).  The Microsoft Surface tablet has also been tested.

There are many features to choose from.  Have a look at the demos and, more importantly, the docs and associated blog posts for more details.

Furthermore, there are many server-side examples that may be helpful during integration of this library into your app.  See the server directory in the Github project.  ASP.NET is one of the many examples.

Comment: +1 This is what we use for uploading to `.ashx` handlers in .NET. Works great